# How do I select a record in a data repeater c#, winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, repeater

I need to know how to delete a selected record from a datarepeater. I know how to do this using a dgv but cannot figure out how to do with a data repeater as using currentrow to pass the value to my query does not seem to apply to repeaters as it does with dgv.  Any help would be great.

Comment: Isn't `DataRepeater` a term from `WebForms`, not `WinForms`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that... you can use DataRepeaters in either winforms for webforms.  I am using winforms for this project.

Comment: Datarepeaters were first available in winforms in VS2008 SP1.

Comment: ok, please disregard my comment.

Comment: @Snowbear: You're not the only one who thought that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry this is VB but I just add a button to the `DataRepeater` and add the following code:

```
BindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
```

Comment: You can format code by indenting the line with 4 spaces, or enclosing the code in backticks (`).

Comment: I love the way that without a semi-colon at the end of the line, it's suddenly VB rather than C#, and therefore requires an apology :)